# Delete a node from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

what i want to do is make a function that will get a list as an input and a number and will delete the node of that list that equals to that particular number. So if i have a linked list lets say:

```
struct num // list 1
{
        char *val;
        struct num *next;
};
```

and i have added 4 items to that list, i want to be able to delete the third item and get back the new list with now 3 items. Everything i have tried till now though wont work, i think because i am not linking the remaining items correctly after i delete one of them.

Since you insist here is what i have till now

```
struct num1 *temp;
    temp = head;

struct num1* deletend(int del){
    for ( int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {   
            if (i == del){
                free(temp);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Link them correctly and it should work.

Comment: What is that everything you have tried? Feel free to post the code. (And no, we will not write your homework.)

Comment: Show a bit more code.  It's not possible for us to help you with what you've shown here.

Comment: You need a `struct num *prev` field too.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey No, he does not.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey : No need for `prev` link. you can delete a node from single linked list too.

Comment: @Denim Idea so nice he needs to be told twice.

Comment: So, where is your delete function? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves the purpose :

```
typedef struct num numNode;  // typedef to escape repeated struct num

numNode* delete_item(numNode* startNode, int position)
{
    int pos = 0;
    numNode* current = NULL;
    numNode* prev = NULL;

    if ((start == NULL) || (position == 0)) // if empty list or 0th item deletion, return the list as it is
        return start;
    else if (position == 1)    // if delete first item,
    {
        current = start;       // this node to be deleted
        start = start->next;   // Set start to the next item

        free current;
        current = NULL;        // delete the node

        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        prev = start;           // this will mark the previous node
        current = prev->next;   // this will mark the current node
        pos = 2;                // position 0, 1 taken care of
    }

    while ((current != NULL))
    {
        if (pos == position)    
        {
            prev->next = current->next;  
            free current;
            current = NULL;
            break;
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return start;
}
```

Comment: A lot better than what i was trying to do thanks.

Comment: Nice code!  However, is it really helpful to dump it on a plate like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the pointer to the previous member to the one deleted.   Then replace the pointer in the previous to the deleted member with the pointer to the next member that was in the deleted member.